# Can the same server be used for both Citrix and Microsoft RemoteApp publishing?

Tags: citrix, windows-terminal-services, remoteapp

We have a QA team that needs to test both Citrix and Microsoft RemoteApp publishing and we are wondering if the same server could be used for both systems. We already have a Citrix environment but need to add a few more servers to the test farm. Would we be able to also setup Terminal Services and use the same server to publish RemoteApp packages or are Citrix and Terminal Services not able to be installed at the same time?

Comment: I haven't used any Citrix products in many years but assuming you mean Citrix XenApp, one of the system requirements is that the TS/RDS role is installed on the server (as it was for Citrix MetaFrame, XP, etc). Saying that, I don't see any issue and I'm a little baffled at the lack of understanding of the basic fundamentals about what Citrix XenApp requires that you and your team have. How is it that you don't know that XenApp requires RDS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can install and run both at the same time. No issues. I've successfully run remote desktop apps independently of Citrix apps from the same server.

If you get an error message about "The initial application you are trying to open is currently unavailable" when you try to open a RemoteApp then you may have to enable the ["Launching of non published programs"](http://support.citrix.com/article/ctx124745) under the Citrix User Policies section of AppCenter